# Код работает только через команду $(document).ready() ... почему?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Начал читать *jQuery*, решил попробовать на практике, но не понятно почему код не работает.

Вот элементы меню, при наведении меняют цвет.

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".navbar a").mouseenter(function(){$(this).addClass('onnavpoint');});})
$(document).ready(function(){$(".navbar a").mouseout(function(){$(this).removeClass('onnavpoint');});})
```

Но если я убираю  `$(document).ready()`, то перестает работать. 
Я далек от мысли, что эту команду перед каждой функцией придется добавлять, поэтому прошу гуру объяснить в чем дело...

Кроме того, `this` вообще зачем здесь? 
я ведь уже обратился к элементу "`.navbar a`" и повесил на него событие. 
Непонятно. Извините за тупость. =(

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Браузер обрабатывает страницы поэлементно сверху вниз, постепенно наполняя dom-дерево (глобальный объект document) Если ваш скрипт подключен в `<head>`, то он выполнится раньше, чем ваше меню, которое, очевидно, лежит *ниже* в `<boby>` окажется в внутри `document`.

Чтобы этого не произошло вы просите браузер зарегистрировать событие — *дождаться*, пока *весь* контент окажется в document и только потом искать в нем .navbar a

Конструкция

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...
});
```

эквивалентна нативной

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    ...
});
```

Событие, которое должно произойти, когда весь html загрузится.

Если вы перенесете вызов вашего скрипта вниз, после объявления `.navbar`, например переда звкрывающим `<\body>` то ваш код будет работать без `$(document).ready(...)`, потому что в тот момент времени, когда браузер дойдет до его выполнения, ваше меню уже будет лежать в `document`.

Теперь далее, никто не мешает вам один раз вызвать

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".navbar a").mouseenter(...);
   $(".navbar a").mouseout(...);
   ...и сколько угодно ещё других действий.
});
```

Но если вы используете jQuery, то подход c `.on()`, который привел в ответе Алексей Шиманский, пожалуй более предпочтителен.

`$(this)` нужен, потому что `addClass` и `removeClass` - *методы* которые есть  *у элемента*, а точнее у объекта jQuery. Если бы вы писали на нативном js, то вам пришлось бы там вместо `this` использовать `event.target`

А вообще я бы советовал начать изучение с нативного js, а не с jQuery. Тогда многие вопросы отпадут.

Comment: А вы умный, спасибо! =)

Comment: А вы где подключаете скрипт в html? Перед закрытием body?

Comment: @DimitarBilkovich в зависимости от размера скриптов, их количества и взаимовлияния друг на друга. А еще существуют атрибуты `defer` и `async` про которые тоже неплохо [знать](https://learn.javascript.ru/script-async-defer).

Answer (score 0):

- `$(document).ready` используют для того, чтобы долждаться, когда загрузиться всё DOM дерево. Иначе при обращению к узлу HTML, которого ещё нет на странице будет ошибка
- Вешать везде где попало `$(document).ready(` не нужно. Можно воспользоваться делегированием и событие вешать на часть, которая всегда есть на странице,в *Jquery* это происходит за счёт **[on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)**. Пример:

  ```
  $(document).on('mouseout', '.navbar a', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('onnavpoint');
  });
  ```
- > this вообще зачем здесь? я ведь уже обратился к элементу ".navbar a"

  `this` указаывает как раз на контекст использования. в данном случае на этот самый элемент, над которым происходит событие. Методы применяются через точку к какому-то элементу. Зная это взаимный вопрос: как *Jquery* должен применить метод без `$(this).`?

Comment: И вы умный, вам тоже спасибо! =)